# How can i display search and filter view in widget?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

I want to display a models search and filter view in the custom widget.

[image]

I want this view and functionality in the custom widget in odoo.

This filter and search view functionality as same as any model in odoo.

Assume one models tree view and its filter and search section as shown in the above picture. The same option comes in widget which comes in tree view.

[image]

The option which are coming in filter view the same option i want in widget.

**Edit 1:**

more clarification in that after some research,

**How to use odoo controlpanel in my custom widget?**